Device tree overlay syntax to add to the root node
Adding to the root node in a device tree overlay is easy enough:
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;
    
/ {
    fragment@0 {
        target-path = "/";
        __overlay__ {
            // ...
        };
    };
};

But when combining this with the syntax that everyone seems to prefer these days, as in
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;
    
/ {
    fragment@0 {
        target-path = "/";
        __overlay__ {
            // ...
        };
    };
};

&spi0 {
    // ...
};

this fails with
ERROR (duplicate_node_names): /fragment@0: Duplicate node name

So my question is whether I have to convert all of my existing &X = { ... }; to fragment@N { target = <&X>; __overlay__ = { ... }; }; just to be able to add to the root node or is there a better way?
